# How to turn member method into a function pointer in PHP?

Tags: php

E.g.

```
class Foo {

    public function testFn($fn) {
        $fn();
    }

    public function hello() {
        echo 'World';
    }
}
```

So, how to pass the `hello` method into the `testFn` method? (By passing I mean to pass any member method in any class)

e.g.

```
 $bar = new Foo();
 $bar->testFn($bar->hello); // this will not work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public function testFn($fn) {
        $this->$fn();
    }

    public function hello() {
        echo 'World';
    }
}

$bar = new Foo();
$bar->testFn('hello');
```

Comment: I want to `$fn` can be method in another class.

Comment: @Howard You really should have mentioned that in the question, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bar = new Foo();
$bar->testFn([$bar, 'hello']);
```

See the documentation for the [`callable` pseudo type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Answer (score 0):

Oh this is weird code... but it works:

```
class Foo {

    public function testFn($fn) {
        $this->$fn();
    }

    public function hello() {
        echo 'World';
    }
}

$bar = new Foo();
$bar->testFn('hello');
```

Comment: Not weird at all :)